# Can/should a reminder-type concept be introduced?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that - while browsing through questions and answers - I regularly come across an interesting question/answer but reading and understanding the answer or answering the question would take quite some time. That's fine, but we all have other things to do as well, don't we? So it happens that I think to myself: I should remember to come back here and fully try to understand this answer or write up an answer to this question when I have more time. (or even adjust an answer following a comment) However, I rarely do.

What is possible (and I have done this before) at the moment is to favourite such questions, but I don't think that's what the 'favourite' option is there for, is it? If it is, this is mostly a suggestion to alter some of its functionality (and add it next to answers as well). If it isn't, here's what I think we could use: something like a reminder, a literal note-to-self. Perhaps a 'Revisit' button, which gives you a similar alert to when people have mentioned you in a comment or something, only that the alert doesn't go away until you have removed it yourself by unclicking the 'Revisit' button for that particular question/answer.

Comment: There are a number of browser plugins and online bookmarking services that can do this for arbitrary web pages.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I realize that, but I don't think that's sufficient enough an argument not to make it an explicit feature of SE itself. Otherwise the "favourite" option is equally unnecessary, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

The "favorite" feature is one that you can (ab)use as much as you want without any problems. When you favorite a question, you get updates delivered to the [favorites tab on your profile.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/16660/wouter?tab=favorites)

Quora has a nice "save draft" feature, which adds the question to an "unanswered questions" tab. I'd be happy if that were implemented, though I don't see that happening.

Also, [this has been proposed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/add-answer-later-tab). It's not [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), so not officially declined yet.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Especially BrunoLM's answer on the MSO question you linked to has some appeal to me. Although perhaps there should then be a limit on the amount of lists per user.